# How to setup certificate authentication for MS SQL server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have to connect an (ADO) application running on a standalone Windows 2003 R2 server to a SQL 2008 R2 database that is a member of the domain.

I have setup an SQL authentication account for this and hard-coded the password into the connection string but I wonder if it wouldn't be possible to use certificate-based authentication for this instead. I haven't been able to find any documentation regarding this apparently new functionality of SQL 2008 R2 anywhere.

Could someone kindly point me at some good documentation ? Or at least a description of the functionality and whether it could be used in my case or not ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you still want help with this, let me know. I have some scripts to create and use SQL Certificate Objects for mirroring purposes in a workgroup situation, that would probably work the same way for your situation.

Comment: Yes, I'm still interested in an answer. Thank you.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment).